# Time complexity of numpy sort

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to compare different algorithms that calculate the biggest diference between two values in one array (for example, on the array [1,2,3,4] the biggest difference is 4-1 = 3).
I used three different algorithms, one that iterates the array 2 times and calculates the difference of each value, it should have a time complexity of **O(n^2)**.
The other algorithm uses **numpy sorting** function and then calculates the difference between the first and the last element (should have a time complexity of **O(n*log(n)**). The other algorithm calculates the biggest and smallest number in the array, the time complexity should be **O(n)**.
When I go to compare the running time results, the second algorithm always runs faster then the third. I don't know why this happens since the time complexity O(n) should be smaller than O(n*log(n)).